# Get computed (USD currency conversion) total of each item

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by, sum, aggregate-functions

I have a query that gets the sum of each item, but when I change the `SUM(d.AMT)` to `(SUM(d.AMT) * e.EXCHANGE_RATE) [USD Amount]` to convert the total to USD I encounter the error:

> Column 'EXCHANGE_RATE.EXCHANGE_RATE' is invalid in the select list
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.

. Can someone please fix my query? Thanks everyone!

```
SELECT d.ITEM_NO, h.ITEM_TYPE, h.ITEM_STATUS, d.CURRENCY,SUM(d.AMT)--(SUM(d.AMT) * e.EXCHANGE_RATE) [USD Amount]
FROM ITEM_HDR h
JOIN ITEM_DET d ON h.ITEM_NO = d.ITEM_NO
JOIN EXCHANGE_RATE e ON d.CURRENCY = e.CURRENCY_FROM
GROUP BY d.ITEM_NO, h.ITEM_TYPE, h.ITEM_STATUS, d.CURRENCY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to multiply *before* the sum:

```
SELECT d.ITEM_NO, h.ITEM_TYPE, h.ITEM_STATUS, d.CURRENCY,
       SUM(d.AMT * e.EXCHANGE_RATE) as [USD Amount]
FROM ITEM_HDR h JOIN
     ITEM_DET d
     ON h.ITEM_NO = d.ITEM_NO JOIN
     EXCHANGE_RATE e 
     ON d.CURRENCY = e.CURRENCY_FROM
GROUP BY d.ITEM_NO, h.ITEM_TYPE, h.ITEM_STATUS, d.CURRENCY;
```

However, if you want this for each item, then simplify the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT d.ITEM_NO, h.ITEM_TYPE,
       SUM(d.AMT * e.EXCHANGE_RATE) as [USD Amount]
FROM ITEM_HDR h JOIN
     ITEM_DET d
     ON h.ITEM_NO = d.ITEM_NO JOIN
     EXCHANGE_RATE e 
     ON d.CURRENCY = e.CURRENCY_FROM
GROUP BY d.ITEM_NO, h.ITEM_TYPE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change 
`(SUM(d.AMT) * e.EXCHANGE_RATE) [USD Amount]` 
To
`SUM(d.AMT * e.EXCHANGE_RATE) AS [USD Amount]`